# ContentChildren not returning result when using ng-template as ng-content

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-template, ng-content

I have a tw-menu component which displays some content with content projection through an ng-content element.

```
<tw-button [data]="data?.Button||{}"></tw-button>
<div class="relative">
    <div [class]="'absolute top'+top+' left'+left+' w'+menuWidth+ ' bg-transparent' " [hidden]="hideMenu">
        <div [class]="'p-2 justify-center w'+menuWidth+' rounded-xl gap-2 flex flex-wrap bg-white'">
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've also implemented a hostlistener to register click events on tw-menu component. After a click event I display in the console the tw-button elements that are part of the ng-content

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tw-menu',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule,TwButtonComponent],
  templateUrl: './tw-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tw-menu.component.scss']
})
export class TwMenuComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() data?:TwMenuData
  
  hideMenu=true

  menuVisibility(){      
    this.hideMenu=!this.hideMenu    
  } 
  
  @ContentChildren(TwButtonComponent) query!:QueryList<TwButtonComponent>  

  @HostListener('click', ['$event.target'])
  onClick() { 
    console.log (this.query.map(x=>x))
    this.menuVisibility()    
  }
```

Now, I have the following template which showcases the problem, which includes two tw-menu elements. The first one passes its content directly with a tw-button component. The second passes the same element, but not directly, but through an ng-template element.

```
<div class="flex">
    <tw-menu [data]="{Button:{Text:'Menu normal'}}">
        <tw-button [data]="{Text:'Option 1'}">
        </tw-button>
    </tw-menu>

    <tw-menu [data]="{Button:{Text:'Menu ng-template'}}">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container>
    </tw-menu>
</div>
<ng-template #content>
    <tw-button [data]="{Text:'Option 1'}">
    </tw-button>
</ng-template>
```

When I click the first tw-menu, the console displays the tw-button component. But when I click the second menu, all I get is an empty array.

I imagine that the problem is that ContentChildren registers children before the ng-template is applied on the template

Is there a solution to this, so I can be able to use the ng-template as data for the ng-content?

.

Comment: Is there any reason to not place the `tw-button` directly in the `tw-menu`? Placing the `tw-button` in the ng-template then reference it later just make the HTML more complex.

Comment: I reuse the ng-template in another part of the template. Specifically for a navbar. For large screens, I use the navbar, for small screens I switch to menu mode.

Comment: As far as I know, I don't think you can get the component reference when you wrap it in the ng-template. There was an github issue that as not solved. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34121

Comment: @skouch2022, is there another way to reference a part of template in various places inside the same template, without having to create a new component?

Comment: If the template is part of the current component's HTML, then YES. You can use `template-variable` to tag the template itself or anything inside the template. Then use `@ViewChild` to reference them. If the template is not part of the current component's HTML and being passed into it, then NO. The passed-in template will be of type `TemplateRef` and it's only useful when you want to render it in the DOM via `*ngTemplateOutlet`.

Comment: @skouch2022, can I use a directive to pass the TemplateRef of the ng-template and then use it in another component?

Comment: If you use a directive to tag or as a wrapper for a `ng-template`, get the `TemplateRef` from that `ng-template` and pass it, then it's still a no.